# Why am I seeing so many Lairon recently?

Tags: pokemon-go

For the last few days, I've been seeing a considerable number of wild Lairon. I don't recall ever seeing a wild Lairon before - only Aron - but over the last few days I must have seen dozens.

[image]

I don't particularly mind, as I have an Aggron with near-perfect IVs that could use the Candy. But **why are so many of them appearing all of a sudden?** I can only assume this is part of an event, but the only one I know of that's happening right now is the Evolution Event, and Lairon doesn't have any special evolutionary requirements, so it's not that.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is part of this [Evolution Event](https://pokemongolive.com/en/post/evolutioneleganza2019/) indeed, even though it has no special evolution requirement. There are more Pokemon that appear more often, for example Haunter, Dragonair and Graveler. Make use of it while it lasts!

Comment: Oh, fair enough, then. Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: Haunter and Graveler at least make sense as they're Trade evolutions, Dragonair and Lairon I guess they just added for fun?

Comment: @IronSean I've also seen a ton of Venomoth. I think they just pulled random evolutions out of a hat or something.